# Missing assembly reference in Razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have a MVC application which works fine when returning JSON for my API controllers. I've added a controller which should return a razor view, however I'm getting the following error when trying to load the page:

> One or more compilation references are missing. Possible causes
> include a missing 'preserveCompilationContext' property under
> 'buildOptions' in the application's project.json.
>
> The type or namespace name 'DevTestViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp.Api.Models' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)

I've simplified my view to:

```
@model List<MyApp.Api.Models.DevTestViewModel>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

My model class is:

```
namespace MyApp.Api.Models {
    public class DevTestViewModel {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I've tried adding a _ViewImports.cshtml:

```
@using MyApp.Api
```

I've also followed the suggestion in the error and set `preserveCompilationContext` in my project.json but it's made no difference:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true
},
```

It works fine when debugging locally. It's only once I publish to Azure that I'm have the problem. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: `project.json` file no longer exists in .Net Core Visual Studio 2017. The problem might have been solved in new version.

Comment: @Win unfortunately upgrading to VS 2017 isn't currently an option. I doubt my problem is an issue with the framework though as I can't get any views with models to work. I'm pretty sure I must just be missing something simple, just not sure where to look.

Comment: I've managed to update to VS 2017 and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was an issue with the deployment to Azure. Re-creating the Web App in Azure and then redeploying fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

nuget install Microsoft.AspNetCore version 1.1.1